# Variable Combination Writer

Tags: excel, combinations, vba

I have VBA program that should create and write out the full combination of up to 7 different variables each with varying levels.

The code loops then all combinations and write them with a space between each variable.  It organizes first by the last line (LineP) and then from first to last (Line1 to Line 6).

The code works so far, except that if a user leaves a line blank it assumes that there are no combinations because an array is empty.
I could solve this by putting **defining the array as " "** but then that leaves an extra two spaces between variables in the combination.
The way the code works right now it would involve not only not writing anything in the variable's spot, but also deleting the space.

The different levels for each variable are stored in an array (Variable 1's levels are in Array1, Variable P's levels are in ArrayP, etc.).  Below is the code that I currently use to write out each combination:

```
`'Create Label Combinations
If Rowi > 1 Then
    Dim Labeli As String
    Dim Rowi2 As Integer
    Rowi2 = Rowi
    If P = 1 Then
        For iP = 0 To UBound(ArrayP)
            For i1 = 0 To UBound(Array1)
                For i2 = 0 To UBound(Array2)
                    For i3 = 0 To UBound(Array3)
                        For i4 = 0 To UBound(Array4)
                            For i5 = 0 To UBound(Array5)
                                For i6 = 0 To UBound(Array6)
                                  Labeli = Array1(i1) & " " & Array2(i2) & _ 
                                         " " & Array3(i3) & " " & _  
                                           Array4(i4) & " " & Array5(i5) & _ 
                                         " " & Array6(i6) & " " & ArrayP(iP)
                                    Cells(Rowi2, 1).Value = Labeli
                                    Rowi2 = Rowi2 + 1
                                Next i6
                            Next i5
                        Next i4
                    Next i3
                Next i2
            Next i1
        Next iP
    End If
End If`
```

An example of the current output is here:

[image]

Since the number of used variables and levels of each variable changes each time I'm not sure a multi-dimension array can be used to solve this.  I thought it might be possible to embed an if statement within the "Labeli" string, but I didn't find anything suggesting that was possible.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried and tested the following, and it does what you expect it to:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Rowi = LastRow + 1
If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
    TempArray1 = Split(TextBox1.Text, ",")
Else
    TempArray1 = Array(" ")
End If

If TextBox2.Text <> "" Then
    TempArray2 = Split(TextBox2.Text, ",")
Else
    TempArray2 = Array(" ") 'if text box is empty add a space to the array (we'll remove the space later)
End If

If TextBox3.Text <> "" Then
    TempArray3 = Split(TextBox3.Text, ",")
Else
    TempArray3 = Array(" ")
End If

If TextBox4.Text <> "" Then
    TempArray4 = Split(TextBox4.Text, ",")
Else
    TempArray4 = Array(" ")
End If

If TextBox5.Text <> "" Then
    TempArray5 = Split(TextBox5.Text, ",")
Else
    TempArray5 = Array(" ")
End If

If TextBox6.Text <> "" Then
    TempArray6 = Split(TextBox6.Text, ",")
Else
    TempArray6 = Array(" ")
End If

If TextBox7.Text <> "" Then
    TempArray7 = Split(TextBox7.Text, ",")
Else
    TempArray7 = Array(" ")
End If

For i1 = 0 To UBound(TempArray1)
    For i2 = 0 To UBound(TempArray2)
        For i3 = 0 To UBound(TempArray3)
            For i4 = 0 To UBound(TempArray4)
                For i5 = 0 To UBound(TempArray5)
                    For i6 = 0 To UBound(TempArray6)
                        For i7 = 0 To UBound(TempArray7)
                            Labeli = TempArray1(i1) & " " & TempArray2(i2) & " " & TempArray3(i3) & " " & TempArray4(i4) & " " & TempArray5(i5) & " " & TempArray6(i6) & " " & TempArray7(i7)
                            Sheet1.Cells(Rowi, 1).Value = Trim(Labeli) 'Change Sheet1 to your Sheets("YourSheetName") or to ActiveSheet
                            Rowi = Rowi + 1
                        Next i7
                    Next i6
                Next i5
            Next i4
        Next i3
    Next i2
Next i1
SpaceKiller 'call spacekiller function to remove all the extra spaces
End Sub

Sub SpaceKiller()
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace _
      What:="  ", _
      Replacement:=" ", _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      MatchCase:=True
'Change Sheet1 to your Sheets("YourSheetName") or to ActiveSheet
   Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Find(What:="  ")
   If r Is Nothing Then
   Else
      Call SpaceKiller
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that would make a lot more sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the combination loops won't write anything if an array is empty since it writes for `iX = 0 to UBound(ArrayX)`.  Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: @YTYT, I've tried and tested the updated answer, please check it as I believe it should do what you wanted it to. Also if this helps you, could you mark my response as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: This answer doesn't allow the user to put just a space in one of the lines, right?  I used your original idea of concatenating the arrays to form the label to solve the issue.  If an array is blank I define it as "Blank" and then set a variable to 1, denoting that the array was blank.  Before adding an array to the label the program checks both if the spot in the array is blank and if the blank variable is equal to 1.  If either of those are true, it doesn't add that array to the label.

Comment: It does allow the user to type a single space, but it won't use that space to create a double space "  " on the labels, as the spacekiller sub will keep looping until all double spaces are replaced with a single space " " from the specified range...

Comment: But what if they want a double-space?

Comment: They wouldn't be able to add a double-space the way it is set up now, if you want them to be able to do that, then the code requires updating, but as that wasn't mentioned on your original post, I didn't even think it might be a requirement..

Comment: It's all good; I just wanted it to be flexible so I created another variable that registers whether or not the array is blank when the array is set up and solves the problem that way.  Thanks for your help!